Representation of a function defined on the unit disk
Show that if $f(z)$ is continuous for $|z| \leq 1$ and analytic for $|z|<1$, and if $|f(z)|=1$ for $|z|=1$, then $f(z)$ can be written as
$$ f(z) = e^{i \varphi} \displaystyle \left(\frac{z-a_1}{1-\overline{a_1}z} \right) \dots \left(\frac{z-a_n}{1-\overline{a_n}z} \right),$$
where $a_1, \dots, a_n \in \mathbb{D}$ and $0 \leq \varphi \leq 2 \pi$.
My Approach : Using the Characterization of Conformal Self Maps (Mentioned in page 263 in Gamelin's book),
If $g(z)$ is a conformal self-map of the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$ such that $g(0)=0$, then $g(z)$ is a rotation, that is, $g(z) = e^{i \alpha} z$ for some fixed $\varphi$, $0 \leq \varphi \leq 2 \pi$.

Isn't the assertion is obvious by this characterization applied to
$$h(z) = \left(\frac{z-a_1}{1-\overline{a_1}z} \right) \dots \left(\frac{z-a_n}{1-\overline{a_n}z} \right) ?$$

What exactly is your question? How to show that every $f$ defined on the closed unit disc with the cited properties is a product of automorphisms of the unit disc and a constant on the unit circle (otherwise known as a Blaschke product)?

@MathsMatador, yes ! I reworded the question appeared in the same book. The proof is evident for one root. The question I have is to extend it to finite number of roots.

Well you can't apply that characterisation directly since it's a result for conformal self maps of the unit disc, which Gamelin defines as analytic bijections. Your given function $f$ is not necessarily a bijection, so the assertion is not an "obvious" consequence.

@MathsMatador, bijection is obvious for each term as it's a conformal self map. So need an argument for bijective for n products.

Are you trying to say that your function $h$ in your question is a bijection?

@MathsMatador, then it would follow from the above characterization as the function is analytic in $D$.

Your $h$ is never a bijection unless it has exactly one factor of the form $(z - a)/(1 - \overline{a}z)$. So you cannot apply the characterisation you speak of.

I'm not sure you can apply the result you're trying to apply since you do not know, apriori that $f$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{D}$. Anyway, one possible approach is the following:
Since $f$ is not identically zero, every zero of $f$ in $\mathbb{D}$ has finite multiplicity. Moreover, $f$ can have only finitely many zeros in $\mathbb{D}$ else they would have a limit point on the unit circle, which is again impossible since $|f| = 1$ there.
Let $a_1,\dots, a_n$ be the zeros of $f$ in $\mathbb{D}$ repeated according to multiplicity. Let $g:\overline{\mathbb{D}}\to\mathbb{C}$ be given by
\begin{equation*}
g(z) = \prod_{k = 1}^n \left(\frac{z - a_k}{1 - \overline{a}_kz}\right).
\end{equation*}
Note that $|g(z)| = 1$ for all $z\in S^1$ and $|g(z)| < 1$ whenever $z\in\mathbb{D}$. The function $h := f/g$ has removable singularities at all the $a_i$'s, $h(a_i)\ne 0$ (since the zeros were repeated according to multiplicity), and $|h(z)| = 1$ for $z\in S^1$.
By construction, $h$ has no zeros in $\mathbb{D}$. The maximum modulus principle on $h$ gives $|h|\le 1$ on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$; on the other hand, the maximum modulus principle applied to $1/h$ (which is holomorphic since $h$ is non-vanishing) gives $|h|\ge 1$. Thus, $|h| = 1$ on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ whence $h$ is a constant $e^{i\varphi}$ for some $0\le\varphi < 2\pi$ and we are done. $\blacksquare$
